# Uppercase in Textfield and add dash automatically after 5 characters

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Convert entered characters to uppercase since PIN can be alphanumeric
and Format pin entry with a dash, after at least 5 characters have been entered.

```
Visibility(
          visible: _pinAttemptsRemaining > 0 && pin != duplicatedValue,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 450),
            child: TextField(
              maxLength: 10,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

              onChanged: (text) {
                pin = text;
              },
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              // keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorText: _errorText,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.dialpad,
                ),
                labelText: '8-digit PIN',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                ),
                errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFF696969), width: 1),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: can you show the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

To do Uppercase

Use TextCapitalization.characters: Capitalize all characters in the sentence.

```
TextField(
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
),
```

Comment: and How to Format pin entry with a dash, after at least 5 characters have been entered?

Comment: you could just do an if statement on the count if it is longer than 5 add a - or a stringbuffer maybe https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a formatter.

```
TextFormField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
    DashFormatter(),
  ],
)
```

Upper Case Formatter

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newValue.text?.toUpperCase(),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Dash Formatter

```
class DashFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (oldValue.text.length > newValue.text.length) {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newValue.text.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newValue.text.length),
      );
    }

    String newText = newValue.text.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'.{5}'), (Match match) => '${match.group(0)} ');
    newText = newText.substring(0, newText.length - 1);

    return TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length),
    );
  }
}
```